# Android Paypal multiple items and open class

Tags: android, paypal

I'd like to charge users for 2 services(in-app), but I am very unfamiliar with the Paypal Android SDK. Here's what I have so far...

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

            PayPalPayment payment2 = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("0.79"), "USD", "Network Fee");

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PaymentActivity.class);

            // comment this line out for live or set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX for sandbox
            intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK);

            // it's important to repeat the clientId here so that the SDK has it if Android restarts your
            // app midway through the payment UI flow.
            intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, "credential-from-developer.paypal.com");

            // Provide a payerId that uniquely identifies a user within the scope of your system,
            // such as an email address or user ID.
            intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYER_ID, "<xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk>");

            intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, "<xxxxxxxxxx.com>");

            intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment2);


           startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
```

I've tried creating multiple intents and PaypalPayment classes, both to no avail. If this is too complex to explain, please link me to a tutorial series.

ps: I would like to have the payment distributed between 2 service providers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the current time, the SDKs only support one simple payment.  I would recommend letting the user pay for the total amount all at once.

Look forward to future enhancements allowing for itemized results early 2014.